# Swift - How to map an array of objects with an function on the object

Tags: swift

I have an array of documents and want to use the `toModel` function on the document to transform all elements.

```swift
let documents = docs.map { $0.toModel() }
```

`toModel()` transforms the struct into another struct.

Is there a nicer, easier or more elegant way to do this?

I thought about something like `let documents = docs.map(\.toModel)`

Comment: If you change `toModel()` to a property called `model` you can do `docs.map(\.model)`

Comment: but I don't want that it is a property. then it gets also parsed to json and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Model` initializer that takes whatever a `doc` is as its argument. “`to`” methods are not Swifty because initializers are so versatile.

```
let documents = docs.map(Model.init)
```

Comment: Because of extensions I think that is a good idea.